# SSL for www.example.com when using a name server

Tags: ssl, nameservers

I have a site www.example.com. I am using a name server, so the content is coming from another IP address. My problem is www.example.com needs to be on SSL to serve the content securely. How can this be set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using a name server, so the content is coming from another IP address.

IP addresses, name servers etc do not matter with HTTPS. All what matters is the hostname (fully qualified, i.e. FQDN) as given in the URL. This hostname must match the subject (CN or subject alternative name) of the certificate. This means if you have control of the system serving this site you can setup a certificate for it. If you don't have control no DNS fiddling like CNAME and not HTTP(s) redirects will help you.